# IOS: use custom cell in some classes

Tags: ios, uitableview, custom-cell

When I crate a custom cell I create a class UITableViewCell and add a nib with a tablecell; it's very clear.
I want to understand how to manage the situation when I should use this custom cell in some classes where I use a tableview.

For example I have a view controller called "FirstViewController" and inside this view controller I have a tableview, I import the class of my tableview cell and I create an IBOutlet for its reference

```
#import "MyCell.h"

IBOutlet MyCell *mycell;
```

In the file's owner of MyCell class in the identity inspector I set the class of FirstViewController, in this way I can link the IBOutlet of my custom cell easily.

In this way I can use MyCell only for FirstViewController, is there a way to share MyCell for other classes as a SecondViewController?

thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a subclass of UITableViewCell, say `CustomCell`. Create a xib file,add a UITableViewCell as root of xib. Change the identity of `UITableViewCell`  as `CustomCell`. Connect outlets to the elements of CustomCell. But don't give ownership to any viewController.

Instantiate with following code in the `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` in any viewController you want

```
CustomCell *customCell = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" 
                                                      owner:nil 
                                                    options:nil][0];
```

Comment: int his way?
static NSString *MyIdentifier = @"MyIdentifier";
 MyIdentifier = @"datacell";
 
 DataCell *cell = (DataCell *)[list dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:MyIdentifier];
 if(cell == nil) {
  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"DataCell" owner:self options:nil];
  cell = dataCell;
 }

Comment: @blackguardian That is almost correct, but the way you suggested you still need to have an IBOutlet for the cell in a VC. If you keep an IBOutlet you will need to make that particular VC as owner of cell. you want to avoid that rite. `if(!customCell)customCell = [[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"CustomCell" 
                                                      owner:nil 
                                                    options:nil][0]; `

Answer (score 1):

"is there a way to share MyCell for other classes as a SecondViewController?"
I would skip the IB case and add programmatically to the SecondViewController.

If you want to stick with IB, than you have to create a custom component, add to XCode, it is possible, but require more time to do it.